# sh script under debian time dependence

Tags: bash, date, time

I've build very simple sh script with curl "url" action ( lights control ) for example when I start playing movie lighits are going off, when movie pause are turnig on. I wanna ask You for help how to build this script...
I want this to check what time is and than if it's day light time for example till 4pm lights will stay turned OFF but after 4 pm lights will response.

I did little research and found time checking command:  HOUR=$(date +"%k")

So if I'm thinking right what is impossibl :) I need something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

HOUR=$(date +"%k")

if (( HOUR >= 7am && HOUR <= 4pm ))  
curl "URL 1 lights control not included"

else 

curl "URL 2 lights control incuded"

fi
```

Thank You in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: you want `date +%H` for the current hour, which will be in 24 hr format. Also remove the am/pm from your comparison. Also turn on hell tracing with `set -x` or super tracing with `set -vx` so you can see what values for variables are being processed. Finally, I'm assuming `"URL 1 ..."` is p-code for what you want to happen AND that  you know a real value to use for URL. I would set those as variables near the top of your script like `URL1=//lightControl&turnON` (or whatever the real values are) and then reference them below like `curl "$URL1"`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good old `case` to the rescue.

```
#!/bin/sh

case $(date +"%H") in
    0[7-9] | 1[0-5] ) url="URL 1 lights control not included" ;;
    * ) url="URL 2 lights control incuded" ;;
esac
curl "$url"
```

The expression matches 07:00:00 through 15:59:59; if you intend for it to match until 16:59:59, the change should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Separate light actions and movie actions.

When pausing movie, check if current hour is greater than or equal to `enable_lights_at`. If yes, turn lights on and pause the movie. When playing movie - first turn the lights off.

```
#!/bin/bash

#
enable_lights_at=16

lights_turn_off() {
    echo "Turning lights OFF";
    curl "URL LIGHTS OFF"
}

lights_turn_on() {
    echo "Turning lights ON";
    curl "URL LIGHTS ON"
}

movie_play() {
    echo "Playing movie";
    lights_turn_off;
    curl "URL PLAY MOVIE"
}

movie_pause() {
    echo "Pausing movie";
    current_hour=$(date "+%k")
    if [ "$current_hour" -ge "$enable_lights_at" ];
    then
        lights_turn_on;
    fi
    curl "URL PAUSE MOVIE"
}

case "$1" in
    'play')
        movie_play;
    ;;
    'pause')
        movie_pause;
  ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {play|pause}"
  ;;
esac
```

Worth checking:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html